# How do I perform the equivalent of the .exit() from a previous version of d3.js to version 5.9.2?

Tags: d3.js

How do I do the equivalent of:

```
this._mappedFromTree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([0, 20]);

var nodesFrom = [];
if (this.rootFrom) {
   nodesFrom = this._mappedFromTree.nodes(this.rootFrom);
}

nodeFrom.enter()...;
nodeFrom.exit().transition().duration(duration).attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
}).style("opacity", 1e-6).remove();
```

From the equivalent 5.9.2 version of:

```
var mappedFrom = d3.tree().size([400, 200]);
var root = d3.hierarchy(source);
mappedFrom(root);
```

How do I get the equivalent of the .exit() so that I can remove collapsed nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer.

```
d3.select(this.$.nodes).selectAll('circle.node').data(root.descendants()).exit()
```

Sorry to have bothered the community.